# How to get a mathematical function as user's input in Python and use it in a loop

Tags: python, function, lambda

I used `f = lambda x: input()` to get a mathematical function as the user's input. I put this in a for loop, but input is requested in every iteration. How do I store the function in a variable only once and use it in the loop?

Here's my code:

```
from math import cos, sin, pow, e

n = int(input('Number of elements in partition: '))
print('The range is set at ...... ')
minimum = int(input('Minimum: '))
maximum = int(input('Maximum: '))
f = lambda x: eval(input('Enter a funtion: '))

fraction = (maximum - minimum) / (n-1)

UpperSum = 0
LowerSum = 0

for i in range(1, n):
    UpperSum = UpperSum + fraction * f(fraction * i)
    LowerSum = LowerSum + fraction * f(fraction * (i - 1))
```

Comment: Have you considered the possibility a malicious user might enter `__import__("shutil").rmtree("/", ignore_errors=False)`?

Comment: In other words, using `eval` is usually a terrible idea, don't do it if you can help it... or put safeguards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specifically made function input part of the function itself:

```
f = lambda x: eval(input('Enter a funtion: '))
```

As the old line goes, "If it hurts when you do that, then don't do that!"
Input the function only once:

```
func_text = input('Enter a function: ')
func_eval = eval(func_text)
f = lambda x: func_eval
```

I broke it down one extra step.  The point, though, is to read the input, evaluate it, and then make *only* that evaluation the function you call.

Comment: Read the comments posted to the OP’s question concerning the use of eval.

Comment: I'm well aware of the dangers; just didn't highlight them in the face of OP's central problem.